# Sharepoint 2010 Validation by two fields

Tags: column, validation

I have a SharePoint list with these fields:

- Destination - User picks a person
- Created by - User who created the item

Is there a way to prevent users from creating item for themselves using validation settings?

Answer (score 0):

By using list validation not column validation. I would need to know more about Destination though. If Destination matches Created by then you can fail and show a message to the user.

Example:

Destination: Smith, John
Created by: Smith, John

```
If(NOT([Destination]=[Created by]), TRUE, FALSE)
```

If the condition valuates to true, the new item will be saved. If not it will display the error message.

Comment: good point Ornery Walrus. I didn't think of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to use either column or list validation to prevent users from creating an item in this way.

This is because the Created By column is not populated until the item is created, and validation occurs before the item is saved. Thus there is nothing to compare the Destination field value against during validation.

In order to prevent users from entering their own name here, you would have to implement some code on the NewForm.aspx page of this list.

Hope this helps!